# A combinatorial identity generalizing identity (3.111) from Gould's book

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove the following identity, which I am sure is correct:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{K}(-1)^m{n \choose m}{(n-m)r-1 \choose n-1}=1,
$$
where $K:=\left[n\frac{r-1}{r}\right]$ for some integer $r$, and $[x]$ denotes the largest integer contained in $x$.

In the special case $r=2$ this is identity (3.111) from H. Gould's book "Combinatorial identities" (1972). For $r=2$ it was first stated by B. C. Wong in Amer. Math. Monthly in May 1930 as an open question. I am wondering if someone has seen a proof of (or can prove) this identity for any $r$. The upper summation limit$\left[n\frac{r-1}{r}\right]$ also occurs in Gould's book in identity (3.113), so it is not entirely unheard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  one can  also be  done using  complex variables.

Suppose we are trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n(r-1)/r\rfloor} {n\choose m} (-1)^m
{(n-m)r-1\choose n-1}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${(n-m)r-1\choose n-1}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{(n-m)r-1}}{z^{n}} \;dz.$$

This integral  sets the range  of the sum, ensuring  that $(n-m)r-1\ge
n-1$ or $(n-m)r\ge  n$ or $n(r-1)\ge mr$ or  $n(r-1)/r\ge m,$ which is
precisely the definition of the constant $K,$ except when $n=m$, where
it yields 
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}
(-1)\times(-2)\times(-3)\times\cdots\times (-(n-1))
= (-1)^{n-1}$$
so we can let $m$ range up to $n$ to obtain
$$-(-1)^{n-1}\times (-1)^n + \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{nr-1}}{z^n}
\sum_{m=0}^n {n\choose m} (-1)^m
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{mr}} \; dz.$$

This is
$$(-1)^{2n} + \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{nr-1}}{z^n}
\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+z)^r}\right)^n \; dz$$
or
$$1 + \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^n(1+z)}
\left((1+z)^r-1\right)^n \; dz$$

This becomes
$$1+[z^{n-1}] \frac{((1+z)^r-1)^n}{1+z}.$$

Note however that $((1+z)^r-1)^n$ starts at $z^n$ and $1/(1+z)$ starts
at $z^0$, so the contribution from the integral is zero, leaving just
$$1$$
as the end result.

**Remark.**  When  $$n(r-1)/r <  m$$  with  $n\ne  m$ we  obtain  that
$(n-m)r-1 < n-1$ but $(n-m)r-1 \ge r-1$ is positive and hence $(1+z)^{(n-m)r-1}$ is a polynomial, producing the value zero for the binomial coefficient except when $m=n.$

Comment: Marko Riedel: thank you very much for answering the question so nicely. I have checked all the details and agree with your proof. May I ask your permission to use it in my future paper (with a reference to you of course)? This identity is by no means a major step in the paper but certainly a very helpful one.

Comment: Good to know that we have independent verification. The integral for the binomial coefficient must be examined carefully to produce the three blocks (block one, the sum, block two, a string of zeros, block three, $(-1)^{n-1}.$) You certainly have my permission to use this. Apparently the technique is due to Egorychev although mathematicians have used the Cauchy Integral Formula to extract coefficients for quite some time.

Comment: Thank you! I have certainly looked at the three blocks as suggested by your remark at the end.

Comment: Search the tag "binomial coefficients" to find more examples of the method by different MSE users.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another proof: view the identity as
$$\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^m\binom{n}{m}\binom{(n-m)r-1}{n-1}=0$$
and $\binom{(n-m)r-1}{n-1}$ as a polynomial in $m$ of degree $n-1<n$.